# Is it possible to destructuring the request in function signature in c# webapi?

Tags: c#, webapi

I have this function that take an object with `UserLogin` and `Tracker` inside.

the way I calling it from the client is: `http.post('url', { userLogin: {..}, tracker: .. })`.

Is it possible to write the arguments without using interface? I mean something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertOrUpdateUserLogin([FromBody] { UserLogin, Tracker })
```

And **without** extacting the arguments like this:

```
 var userLogin = data.UserLogin
 var tracker = data.tracker
```

The code:

```
[HttpPost("user-login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertOrUpdateUserLogin([FromBody] UserLoginData data)
{
    PersonalizationUserLogin userLogin = data.UserLogin;
    int tracker = data.Tracker;

    // Rest of your code to insert or update user login

    return Ok("Operation completed successfully");
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with current code (i.e. `data.UserLogin` ...)?

Comment: it makes me to write interface for that. UserLoginRequest. 
I dont need another interface, just UserLogin have interface and Tracker is int

Comment: Interface? Not a class, interface?

Comment: Sorry. class. you right.

Comment: What is the problem with stating the type of a parameter? That's normal C# rules. Javascript allows destructuring, this is not javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no. It is not possible to bind multiple `FromBody` parameters:

> Don't apply `[FromBody]` to more than one parameter per action method. Once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other `[FromBody]` parameters.

So something like `InsertOrUpdateUserLogin([FromBody] UserLoginData userLogin, [FromBody] int tracker})` becomes impossible.

There is no shorthand syntax allowing to define anonymous type as method parameter (and which will be bound correctly, so [(value) tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) will not work too).

Note that you are posting a single JSON object as request so it makes a lot of sense to just create a type to represent it. Which is extremely easy with [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) for example:

```
public record InsertOrUpdateUserLoginRequest(UserLoginData UserLogin, int Tracker)
```

And use it:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertOrUpdateUserLogin([FromBody] InsertOrUpdateUserLoginRequest data)
```

Otherwise you will need to pass tracker in some other way (query string parameter or header for example).

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of this [TupleModelBinder library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/M6T.Core.TupleModelBinder) ([github](https://github.com/m6t/M6T.Core.TupleModelBinder/tree/master))

```
[HttpPost("user-login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertOrUpdateUserLogin(
   (UserLogin userLogin, Tracker tracker) request)
{
    PersonalizationUserLogin userLogin = request.userLogin;
    int tracker = request.tracker;
    ...
}
```